# 2 large databases - worth merging into 1?

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I have 2 large databases that were shared before.  I now have removed the sharing and have created a new database with all of the data except for the tables that were originally shared.  Is it worth importing this data into the new database, or keeping them as separate entities that I can just scan through?  We are talking around 60million records in each shared table, of which there are 2 tables.

Also, whilst I have an empty table, should I be adding indexes which weren't thought of when the database was originally constructed and now too large to add them?

Comment: that all depends on what you are planning to do with the data, and why you sharded them in the first place.

Comment: The problem is, I didn't shard them.  I inherited the system and the sharding wasn't configured correctly.  So, I need to be able to still utilise the data, for reporting, but am not sure whether it's worth merging into the new database structure (without sharding).  Hope that makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to merge the databases.  I took a good look at what indexes were missing and adding them whilst the table was empty.  These indexes have improved the speed and efficiency of the large tables.